# Is there any google Chinese web font that is free?

Tags: fonts

I need free Chinese Google font for my web.

Beside the website below, is there any google Chinese web font that is free?

https://www.google.com/fonts/earlyaccess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check: [Google Noto Fonts](https://www.google.com/get/noto/)

[image]

Also read : [Chinese Standard Web Fonts](http://www.kendraschaefer.com/2012/06/chinese-standard-web-fonts-the-ultimate-guide-to-css-font-family-declarations-for-web-design-in-simplified-chinese/)

Comment: Is there a webfont for them?